# Object duplicated when using processing.Manager?

Tags: python, process

I'm trying to use processing.Manager to share data between processes (processing.Manager.list, processing.Manager.dict, ...). But, when i use it, object are duplicated:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def manipulate_in_process(objects):
    objs = []
    for obj in objects:
        objs.append(obj)
    print('foo objs', objs)

def do_in_process(objects):
    print('objects', objects)
    manipulate_in_process(objects)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    objects = [object(), object()]
    print('main objects', objects)
    shared_objects = manager.list(objects)
    process = Process(target=do_in_process, args=(shared_objects,))
    process.start()
    process.join()
    print('finish')
```

Output:

```
main objects [<object object at 0xb72a64a8>, <object object at 0xb72a64b0>]
objects [<object object at 0xb72a64a8>, <object object at 0xb72a64b0>]
foo objs [<object object at 0xb72a64e8>, <object object at 0xb72a64c0>]
finish
```

Shareds objects are duplicated when used: **0xb72a64a8** != **0xb72a64e8**.

1. I'm doing it wrong ?
2. Why these objects are duplicated ?
3. How can i use objects with processing.Manager.list/dict/etc ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do here? You're obviously not just sharing objects to print their IDs. Whatever you're _really_ trying to do may be doable, or even easy, but it's hard to guess without knowing what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much inherent that objects are copied, not shared, between processes. That's the definition of separate processes: that they have separate heaps with separate objects.

If you want actual shared data, you have to use `Value`, `Array`, or `sharedctypes`—but of course in that case, you're limited to "native" values and those you can express in terms of C structs. And, even then, there's no guarantee that the `id` will be the same across processes, only that the value itself will be.

The point of `Manager` is that you can put an object like, say, a `list` in a server process, and a proxy to that object in each child process. The list proxy looks like a real list as far as core list functionality goes (iteration, indexing, `append`, `insert`, `index`, etc.). But the proxy doesn't try to fake "under-the-covers" introspection functionality like `id`.

The exact list of types that can be proxied by `Manager` out of the box differs between Python versions, but you can find it in the docs for your version. As of 3.4, it includes `list`, `dict`, `Namespace`, `Lock`, `RLock`, `Semaphore`, `BoundedSemaphore`, `Condition`, `Event`, `Barrier`, `Queue`, `Value` and `Array`. At any rate, it's never going to include `object`, because `object` *has* no functionality beyond the under-the-covers stuff.

Of course you can register your own types with the `Manager` with custom proxies. But I'm not sure what you'd want to share with `object`.

See [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for an overview and [Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) for full details.